# Solution to travelling salesman problem using nearest neighbour algorithm in one LINQ query?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Given

```
List<Point> cities = /* ... */ ;
double distance(Point a, Point b) { /* ... */ };
```

is there a single LINQ query that returns the travelling salesman shortest route by nearest neighbour algorithm as a `List<int>` of the indices of `cities`?

Comment: by "nearest neighbour" you think of "go to the next closest citiy"? Well you can sureley do this with a linq-chain but this almost read like *homework* ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do everything in a single query, some parts of the algorithms will have to be implemented separately.

Here's a brute-force implementation that examines all city permutations and returns the shortest path that visits all the cities:

```
var bestPath =
   cities.Permutations()
      .MinBy(
        steps => steps.Aggregate(
                    new { Sum = 0, Previous = default(Point) },
                    (acc, c) =>
                        new
                        {
                            Sum = acc.Sum + (acc.Previous != null ? Distance(c, acc.Previous) : 0 ),
                            Previous = c
                        },
                    acc => acc.Sum));
```

The `Permutations` extension method is defined as follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Permutations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    var query =
        from item in source
        from others in source.SkipOnce(item).Permutations()
        select new[] { item }.Concat(others);
    return query.DefaultIfEmpty(Enumerable.Empty<T>());
}

public static IEnumerable<T> SkipOnce<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T itemToSkip)
{
    bool skipped = false;
    var comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (!skipped && comparer.Equals(item, itemToSkip))
            skipped = true;
        else
            yield return item;
    }
}
```

Of course there are much better approaches to solve this problem, but this one works... Most of it is in a single query, the only parts that are implemented separately are not specific to the problem at hand and can be reused for other tasks.

EDIT: oops, I just realized I also used the non-standard `MinBy` method; you can find it [in the MoreLinq project](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs)

Comment: Thomas, @digEmAll, thanks both. I could not choose between your two equally good answers so I ticked the first.

Comment: @ChrisJJ, actually digEmAll's answer is closer to what you asked; my algorithm doesn't use the "closest neighbor" heuristic (it uses no heuristic at all, it just tries every possible path and returns the best one)

Answer (score 2):

If you just need Nearest Neighbour algorithm in one single LINQ query, you can do in this way:

```
var nearestNeighTour = cities.Skip(1).Aggregate(
new List<int>() { 0 },
(list, curr) =>
{
    var lastCity = cities[list.Last()];
    var minDist = Enumerable.Range(0, cities.Count).Where(i => !list.Contains(i)).Min(cityIdx => distance(lastCity, cities[cityIdx]));
    var minDistCityIdx = Enumerable.Range(0,cities.Count).Where(i => !list.Contains(i)).First(cityIdx => minDist == distance(lastCity, cities[cityIdx]));
    list.Add(minDistCityIdx );
    return list;
});
```

Even if I think it's more readable using  for-loops